# Jboss AS 7 LdapExtLoginModule Configuration

Tags: java, security, configuration, jboss, ldap

Cannot work out why this isn't working on my test server.  Glassfish 3 is authenticating using the same LDAP details so I was hoping someone here could help.  All I get in logs is a password incorrect/password required error which seems could be anything wrong in configuration causing this issue.  I have SSL working correctly on my Jboss server so far and now just need to get this issue sorted.

```
dn: uid=<user name>,ou=people,dc=vts,dc=com
uid: <user name>
homeDirectory: /home/<user name>
gidNumber: <group number>
userPassword: <Password1>
cn: <user name>
uidNumber: <uidnum>

dn: cn=<group name>,ou=group,dc=vts,dc=com   
userPassword: <Password1>
gidNumber: <group number>
cn: <group name>
```

My domain.xml security config is:

```
<security-domain name="myRealm">
   <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">  
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>   
      <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldaps://xxx.xxx.x.x:xxx"/>  
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>                        
      <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=<user name>,dc=vts,dc=com"/>
      <module-option name="bindCredential" value="<Password1>"/>
      <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=vts,dc=com"/>
      <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>                                 
      <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=group,dc=vts,dc=com"/>                                
      <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(&amp;(objectclass=posixGroup)(gidnumber=<group number hardcoded>)))"/>
      <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="ou"/>                
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </security-domain>
```

I have a jboss-web.xml with my security domain name in it (myRealm).  Even just knowing that this musch is configured correct for my setup from the ldap info above would be useful so I know to look elsewhere.  Thanks.

edit:

Add server log stacktrace:

`[Server:server-one] 14:19:11,605 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8081-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:270) [picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:180) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of this error by moving all logging to debug level logging which got me more meaning ful errors.

Then worked through the errors which were SSL related so though SSL was working for my applications deployed using the connector, for LDAP, I needed to add the system properties defined below:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="cacerts.jks"/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" value="Password1"/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.keyStore" value="/keystore.jks"/>
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword" value="Password1"/>
    <property name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
    <property name="java.security.policy" value="server.policy"/>
</system-properties>
```